# How can I properly handle 404, internal errors and any other errors in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I read this entire thread and I'm still scratching my head...

[How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc)

A lot of the stuff is good. I specially liked the unicorn solution (the other solutions are old or overengineered). It still does not seem to be the ultimate solution however.

Are there any other, newer alternatives, more suited to the latest technologies/frameworks? Perhaps Microsoft has some built-in features that I don't know of? I mean after all, this is MVC **5** and one would think that after all of these years something this fundamental would come built-in, out of the box (like all the ASP.NET Identity features for instance) - the only thing the developer would need to do is to make the NotFound and ServerError views prettier!